# 3d models animation in webgl

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am new to webgl and am trying to animate objects, **not simply rotating/moving** them but complex motions. For example how can we make movements of hand/leg in a human model(as if the person is walking)?Right now I am using **Three.js** to import the OBJ model.

Comment: If you want complex animation, you'll need to do some mesh skinning and bone animation. OBJ format doesn't support that kind of information (in fact it only stores static polygonal data).

Comment: Can you give any link or example description on how to proceed exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I used Blender 2.64 and Three.js exporter successfully to load animated model in the scene. Here is nice tutorial that explains everything from animation in Blender to exporting to Three.js (although it uses older version of exporter so the things you make won't work in their test application).

http://www.kadrmasconcepts.com/blog/2012/01/24/from-blender-to-threefab-exporting-three-js-morph-animations/